What do we know about the pre-colonial nature of Tutsi vs Hutu relations?
There was a massive genocide in Rwanda in 1994 when close to a 500k-1M ethnic Tutsis were massacred by ethnic Hutus in the space of three months.
(The population of Rwanda is 13M, about 85% Hutu, 15% Tutsi.  And with a very high population density of 517/km2.)
Both ethnicities have been co-located in Rwanda for a long time.  Germany was the colonizer from 1897 until 1916 when Belgium took over till 1959 (a Hutu-led revolution massacred Tutsis even then).
Now, the Hutus did have reasons to resent the Tutsis.  Tutsis apparently had put in place a system where they were effectively in charge and Hutus traditionally needed the patronage of a Tutsi representative to, for example, seek redress from another Tutsi.
A counter argument goes that it was the Belgian colonialists who caused the Tutsi-over-Hutu oppressive system to develop.  As they a) liked the Tutsis better and b) found it expedient to "divide and conquer" by empowering the Tutsi minority  and make them dependent upon them.  One typical cited fact is that Belgians required ethnicity to be marked on IDs.
In other words, before the Belgians came, there was no societal problem with Tutsis lording it over Hutus, according to "some people blogging around".  But also more credible sources, like Le Monde Diplomatique
Wikipedia's entry seems to somewhat downplay pre-existing stress points:
(I'll cite the whole thing since my non-citation of wikipedia has been a point of contention.  Some sections italized when they are are part of a larger, less relevant, paragraph)

The population coalesced, first into clans (ubwoko),[21] and then, by 1700, into around eight kingdoms.[22] The Kingdom of Rwanda, ruled by the Tutsi Nyiginya clan, became the dominant kingdom from the mid-eighteenth century,[23] expanding through a process of conquest and assimilation,[24] and achieving its greatest extent under the reign of King Kigeli Rwabugiri in 1853–1895. Rwabugiri expanded the kingdom west and north,[25][23] and initiated administrative reforms which caused a rift to grow between the Hutu and Tutsi populations.[25] These included uburetwa, a system of forced labour which Hutu had to perform to regain access to land seized from them,[26] and ubuhake, under which Tutsi patrons ceded cattle to Hutu or Tutsi clients in exchange for economic and personal service.[27] Although Hutu and Tutsi were often treated differently, they shared the same language and culture, the same clan names, and the same customs; the symbols of kinship served as a unifying bond between them.[28]: 421


Rwanda and neighbouring Burundi were assigned to Germany by the Berlin Conference of 1884,[29] and Germany established a presence in the country in 1897 with the formation of an alliance with the king.[30] German policy was to rule the country through the Rwandan monarchy; this system had the added benefit of enabling colonization with small European troop numbers.[31] The colonists favoured the Tutsi over the Hutu when assigning administrative roles, believing them to be migrants from Ethiopia and racially superior.[32] The Rwandan king welcomed the Germans, using their military strength to widen his rule.[33] Belgian forces took control of Rwanda and Burundi in 1917 during World War I,[34] and from 1926 began a policy of more direct colonial rule.[35][36] The Belgians modernised the Rwandan economy, but Tutsi supremacy remained, leaving the Hutu disenfranchised.[37]


In the early 1930s, Belgium introduced a permanent division of the population by classifying Rwandans into three ethnic (ethno-racial) groups, with the Hutu representing about 84% of the population, the Tutsi about 15%, and the Twa about 1%. Compulsory identity cards were issued labeling (under the heading for "ethnicity and race") each individual as either Tutsi, Hutu, Twa, or Naturalised. While it had previously been possible for particularly wealthy Hutus to become honorary Tutsis, the identity cards prevented any further movement between the groups[38] and made socio-economic groups into rigid ethnic groups.[39]


The ethnic identities of the Hutu and Tutsi were reshaped and mythologized by the colonizers.[28] Christian missionaries in Rwanda promoted the theory about the "Hamitic" origins of the kingdom, and referred to the distinctively Ethiopian features and hence, foreign origins, of the Tutsi "caste".[28][40] These mythologies provide the basis for anti-Tutsi propaganda in 1994.[28]: 421  Starkly contrasted, the Tutsi origin myth holds that Kanyarwanda had several sons, including Gatutsi and Gahutu, ancestors of the Tutsi and Hutu who are therefore brothers. The Hutu origin myth holds that Kigwa (patrilineal ancestor of Ruhanga and the first Tutsi) fell from the sky on an earth inhabited by Hutu.[41]: 65

Question:  Is this claim, that the mutual dislike between Hutus and Tutsis, and factual Tutsi oppression, was mostly Westerners' fault, credible?  What is the historical record telling us?
To give some background, I read a book in French a long time ago (Civilizations Africaines, I believe).  It was written before 1994 and generally seemed both well researched and highly pro-African (for example, the author criticized how, when encountering very high quality stone fortresses deep in the continent, Western historians quickly began to spin up claims of European involvement, claiming that the locals couldn't possibly have been that skilled stonemasons).
But, like I said, written before 1994's genocide.  To paraphrase from memory what was only a page or so, covering the Tutsi-Hutu relations:

Yes, Westerners criticize this but they don't know what they're talking about.
The Tutsis and Hutus have a well established system that allows the society to operate well, with customs to handle disputes and negotiations.
I don't recall any mention of it being put in place by colonial administration.

It really was chilling to be reading this, not long after the genocide.  Clearly the author would have never written such a candidly glowing coverage of the customs of Tutsi to Hutu relations afterwards.
Now, I have no reason to disbelieve that colonial administrators may have deliberately empowered the Tutsi minority over the Hutus even more, as a way to facilitate their rule or out of sheer prejudice.  But were the prevalence of Tutsi individuals' rights over Hutu individual rights, justified by ethnicity, an established custom before the colonial period?
p.s. No, this question isn't trying to play down the lack of interests and involvement by Western countries in not intervening in 1994, which is greatly shameful.
p.p.s.  I know this is a contentious subject.  There are obvious benefits to blaming colonial powers for this state of affairs.  But there are also obvious benefits for a colonial power to increase ethnic divisions to facilitate its own rule.  Belgium's history in Congo was atrocious, so please don't assume I am taking its side.
p.p.p.s
from a comment:

The question is interrogating a straw man. Where exactly does the Braekman article you link to (or any other relevant source) claim that "mutual dislike between Hutus and Tutsis" and/or "factual Tutsi oppression" was created whole cloth by the Belgians?

Maybe that particular article did not.  How about this one, from the USC Shoah foundation - Genocide Against the Tutsi in Rwanda:

The roots of the genocide lay in Rwanda’s colonial past. A German colony until 1916, Belgium took control of Rwanda after Germany’s defeat in World War I. Belgian colonial administration favored Tutsis over Hutus using racist beliefs to justify their discriminatory practices. These beliefs claimed that because Tutsis were, wrongly, assumed to have a different bone structure, including thinner noses and higher cheekbones, they must come from European or North African descendants, unlike the Hutus, who were shorter, had wider noses, and therefore determined to be from African descendants. The Belgians employed the colonial model of “divide and rule,” which allowed them to rely on indirect rule by Tutsi elites. Part of the “divide and rule” strategy included the introduction of ethnic identity cards, which solidified the identities of Hutu and Tutsi, which had previously referred more to social status and wealth. In other words, colonialism introduced ethnic conflict into a social structure where ethnicity previously did not exist. Later, in post-colonial history, this antagonism evolved into a systematic, genocidal ideology that pitted the Hutus against the Tutsis and justified the extermination of Tutsis.

Is that definitive enough to motivate this question?  Because it certainly comes right out and makes a statement that is only implied in the wikipedia background section.

"both groups are visibly distinct from each other" This contradicts every other source I've read.  What research have you done into pre-colonial relations? What is wrong with Wikipeda? You cite Wikipedia, but the conclusions you draw are markedly different. I think all the questions you asked are address in the background section  of that article.

I wonder at your insistence on filtering all questions through wikipedia.  Wikipedia is not the end all and be all of knowledge sources, especially not on controversial subjects.  For example, the page on Salafism was unusable for years as pro-Salafists and anti-Salafits duked it out.  The page on Thugs in India has had extensive rewrites over time.  I am unsure that your role as a moderator involves pushing requirements that are not, to my knowledge, part of the formal rules of this forum.

Issues with the way I moderate should be addressed in meta, not here.

Black people of different parts of Africa can be as visually different as say Norwegians and Italians, which no one would seriously claim do not have aggregate visual differences.  And that applies especially to herder-based nomads like the Masai.  I grew up in the Caribbean, which is populated by the descendants of West African slaves.  They look very very different from some people from East Africa that I can see, with my own 2 eyes where I live now.

The claim of Tutsi ancestry from European descent is sheer gibberish.  Doesn't mean that there are no visual differences.  Making this particular citation rather pointless.

Antagonism between herding peoples and farming peoples is so universal that its even the central antagonizing force in the musical Oklahoma! (and also in nearly every American western ever made). This issue is as old as the Neolithic. The problem the colonizers introduced wasn't the existence of Hutus or Tutsis, it was the existence of "Rwanda" as the political unit both were forced to compete to govern.

@T.E.D. Forced regrouping of distinct peoples with a country, without regards for local history and customs is often the case indeed with other parts of Africa, where the colonial borders were drawn from European capitals without regard for tribal groupings.  Even in some cases without the lands having been surveyed.  But I do have the sense the 2 groups had a long history of co-existence, at the same location, before modern Rwanda.

@ItalianPhilosopher - I've yet to dive into the folklore and archology, but I'd be surprised if we discovered the relations between farming and herding peoples in that corner of sub-saharan Africa was far more sunshine and rainbows than the places we do have written history for in Eurasia. (Huns, Turks, Scytihans, Mongols, etc.). I know some people like to make this same co-existence claim about Pre-Columbian Native Americans, I have looked into that, and its utter nonsense.

@T.E.D. Well, that is what this question is about.  How much of the strife was European-induced vs how much had been in place before colonization.  This is precisely the type of subject where wikipedia can have some weaknesses.

I am removing (both groups are visibly distinct from each other, in the same sense as say Italians vs Norwegians).  While I stand by my statement, this isn't strictly necessary for this question and is only causing controversy.

The question is interrogating a straw man. Where exactly does the Braekman article you link to (or any other relevant source) claim that "mutual dislike between Hutus and Tutsis" and/or "factual Tutsi oppression" was created whole cloth by the Belgians? This would be a gross oversimplification of what is widely understood: that the Belgians took a pre-existing class distinction and transformed it into an ethno-racial one.

I know very little about this conflict, only that one of them was a herding culture and the other pastoral. That is always a source for conflict. You should look here for reasons and details.

This is an interesting question and I don't see the existing answer proving a full response.  I am puzzled by the number of downvotes.  You may want to tone this down (by deleting "chilling" etc.).

I'll give a basic pre-colonial history overview. I hope this helps.
Prior to (very roughly) the Common Era, the people living in that area of Africa were hunter-gatherers, possibly speaking something akin to proto-Khoisan. The nearby Sandawe people still speak a language from this family (or at least quite similar, and nothing like Bantu).
After this point came what we call the Bantu Expansion of Bantu (Niger-Congo) speaking farmers and herders with full-blown iron tools advanced from West to East across the top of the peninsula of Africa, and then down through the entire tropical peninsula of southern Africa, where their crop package worked. Any sparse hunter-gatherers living in that area would have had very little chance to compete. By about 500CE, they were essentially done. The Linguistic map of Africa would have looked like this:

When Europeans arrived in the area, they found 3 ethnicities, split by their food production strategies, social status, and perhaps to a lesser extent physical attributes, but all speaking the same language. The Hutu (farmers), Tutsi (pastoralists), and Twa (hunter-gatherers). Their relative numbers are about what you'd expect given the relative productivity of those 3 food-production strategies: Hutu > Tutsi >> Twa (where ">" is "an order of magnitude more"). The Tutsi, despite being greatly in the minority, were largely ruling the area, one might speculate due to the advantage their experience in the saddle at a time when (in the absence of gunpowder) cavalry had a large advantage over infantry.
What happened between those two events is not well documented. There are theories, but, there are disputes, and the disputes have become tied up in political differences that have in the past led to genocide. So we should try to be very careful here.
Since they all speak the same language, one theory (a) is that they were all originally the same Bantu peoples, who specialized and formed into castes. There is another case of closed castes among the Batu peoples: The Namu blacksmiths. However, that's based more on a job people in settlements might have. The fact that the Rwandan "castes" are on much harder cultural\lifestye boundaries, I find kind of suspicious.
The other theory is that (b) the Twa are indigenous people who possibly spoke something like Khoisan before they got swamped by the Bantu expansion. Their original language was lost because they were so massively swamped by the farming Hutus (like more that 100 to 1). (c) Much later Tutsi pastoralists migrated into the area from the north, likely around the 18th Century when the Masai pastoralists did the exact same thing on the other side of Lake Victoria. They may well have even originally been the same people as the Maasai, before assimilating into the local Kinyarwandan culture, much like the Norse Varagians did in slavic Russia at around the same time.
According to the Tutsi origin myths, their two peoples were descended from brothers. According to the Hutu origin myths, when the Tutsi moved into the area, Hutus were already living there. According to the Twa, they were there before either the Hutus or the Tutsis arrived in the area. This means that the Hutu oral history supports theory c, the Tutsi one a, and the Twa one b and not a (but doesn't rule out c). The Twa story also meshes well with our existing theories of the Bantu Expansion, but still its just their myth.
Genetically, the Hutus and Tutsis are quite similar, and both seem far and away descended from Bantus peoples. That does seem to support theory a, but our historical example of the Varangians looks very much like this in modern DNA, so that's not a decisive case. There are also some intriguing differences. Hutus seem to be much more likely to carry the sickle-cell trait common among Niger-Congo peoples (like the Bantu), while Tutsis are much more likely to have lactatose tolerance traits, which are much more common among Nilotic peoples. To be fair, that trait also makes being a pastoralist far easier of a life, so it would have been naturally selected for amongst the Tutsi either way.
However, for the purposes of this question, I'm not entirely sure which theory holds matters all that much. The facts upon the dawn of the historical record are that we had a small (10-20%) cultural group of pastoralists ruling over a large majority (80-90%) of farming peoples. The historical examples of this happening in recorded history (Goths, Scyths, Mongols, Turks, Huns, etc.) are pretty much universally that this state of affairs gets established, and maintained, by force. It seems quite fair to assume that was the case here as well, and anyone arguing otherwise IMHO is going to have to assume the burden of proof for their historically unusual theory.

Do you mean "lactose intolerance"?

@MikhailKatz - Nope, tolerance. Most humans do not have much ability to digest lactase, the cow milk enzyme. For those that can digest it, like some of the Tutsis (and perhaps most Europeans), the genes allowing for lactose tolerance can be seen.

T., I don't have a medical degree, but when you write "do not have much ability to digest lactase" what you probably mean is "do not have much ability to digest lactose".  Meanwhile, lactase is the enzyme that enables the intestine to digest the sugar lactose contained in milk.  So you are saying that the Europeans are just about the only ones to be able to drink cow milk without any problem?  That's interesting, I didn't know that.

@MikhailKatz - "Just about the only ones?" Not quite. Only about 35% of the world is what we'd call lactose tolerant, and the distribution is basically herding peoples around the world, and Europeans. Since herding peoples (as mentioned in the answer above) have an order of magnitude less population density than farmers, that means a lot of the lactose tolerant people in the world today are indeed Europeans (and perhaps hints at a distant herding past for Europeans' Indo-European ancestors).
